# SHIPPING ISSUE WITH MATRIX RATE

Tags: magento-1.9

Currently on my site I offer 5 methods of shipping:

3 - 5 day shipping , recorded delivery , special next day , courier , special saturday.

By default 3 - 5 day delivery is charged at 4.50 unless the order is greater than £70 then they get this for free. I have a shipping rule set up for this.

This issue I am having when the total value is over £200 then the user qualifies for free courier but the option checks by default but doesn't change it to free it just shows the price next to it?

Forgot to add I am using webshopapps matrix rates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Magento 1.9, if you are using webshopapps matrix rates then you have to add **minimum order amount for free shipping**. You can the see the field in screenshot

[image]

There is file in webshopapp matrix rate **Matrixrate.php**

> Path of file: app\code\community\Webshopapps\Matrixrate\Model\Carrier

This is one of the screenshot of my code ignore other condition and just check the highlighted condition which check the minimum order amount threshold if agrees the condition freeshipping flag becomes true

[image]

I hope this will help

Comment: @tom Bannister I can give you the code solution as well if it doesn't work. I have decent amount of experience working with shipping methods of magento 1.9

Comment: Hi there, Would it be possible to get the code example as it maybe better for me as i am fairly new to . magento

Comment: @tom if my answer is helpful to you please upvote my answer so it helps other readers as well. keep coding :) thanks